# Selecting CPUs and memory in Vagrant

Tags: ruby

I generally like to be Rubocop-clean, but it seems like breaking up the first case statement will only make things harder to read. Any suggestions?

```
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.provider 'virtualbox' do |vb|
    vb.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--memory', host_hardware[:memory],
                  '--cpus', host_hardware[:cpus], '--ioapic', 'on']
  end

  private

  # rubocop:disable Metrics/AbcSize, Metrics/MethodLength
  def host_hardware
    case RUBY_PLATFORM
    when /linux/
      cpus = `nproc`.to_i
      memory = `sed -n -e '/^MemTotal/s/^[^0-9]*//p' /proc/meminfo`.to_i / 1024
    when /darwin/ # OS X
      cpus = `sysctl -n hw.ncpu`.to_i
      memory = `sysctl -n hw.memsize`.to_i / 1024 / 1024
    when /cygwin|mswin|mingw|bccwin|wince|emx/ # Windows
      cpus = `wmic computersystem get numberofprocessors`.split("\n")[2].to_i
      memory = `wmic OS get TotalVisibleMemorySize`.split("\n")[2].to_i / 1024
    else 
      cpus = 2
      memory = 2048
    end
    { cpus: cpus, memory: reasonable_memory(memory) }
  end
  # rubocop:enable Metrics/AbcSize, Metrics/MethodLength

  def reasonable_memory(memory)
    half_of_memory = memory / 2
    case
    when half_of_memory < 1024
      1024
    when half_of_memory > 4096
      4096
    else
      half_of_memory
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd start by breaking the `host_hardware` method into `host_cpus` and `host_memory` rather than returning a hash. A hash feels like a too "informal" structure.

Of course, you'll then need to do the `case` switching in multiple places, but you can streamline that a little bit by having a method that just returns a normalized platform identifier:

```
def host_platform
  case RUBY_PLATFORM
  when /linux/ then :linux
  when /darwin/ then :darwin
  when /cygwin|mswin|mingw|bccwin|wince|emx/ then :windows
  else :generic
  end
end
```

You'll still need `case` statements elsewhere, but at least they'll be simpler.

Alternatively, you can define the cpu/memory "getters" as procs or lambdas in a hash keyed by the platform:

```
# horrible name, but it's late
cpu_getters = {
  linux: -> { `nproc`.to_i },
  darwin: -> { `sysctl -n hw.ncpu`.to_i },
  windows: -> { `wmic computersystem get numberofprocessors`.split("\n")[2].to_i }
}
```

And a similar thing for getting memory information, of course.

Then, using the `host_platform` from before, you can so something like:

```
def host_cpus
  getter = cpu_getters[host_platform]
  getter ? getter.call : 2
end
```

And again, similar thing for memory.

Or, going all out, you could make "platform" classes with `cpus` and `memory` methods. If you need more than cpu and memory info,

Playing around a bit, I came up with the thing below. I know that is probably *waaaay* over-engineered for a simple vagrant file, but between one extreme and the other, you might find something useful.

```
module Platform
  def self.current
    case RUBY_PLATFORM
    when /linux/ then Linux.new
    when /darwin/ then Darwin.new
    when /cygwin|mswin|mingw|bccwin|wince|emx/ then Windows.new
    else Generic.new
    end
  end

  class Generic
    attr_reader :cpus, :memory

    def initialize
      @cpus = 2
      @memory = 2048
    end

    def reasonable_memory
      [1024, memory / 2, 4096].sort[1]
    end
  end

  class Linux < Generic
    def initialize
      @cpus = `nproc`.to_i
      @memory = `sed -n -e '/^MemTotal/s/^[^0-9]*//p' /proc/meminfo`.to_i / 1024
    end
  end

  class Darwin < Generic
    def initialize
      @cpus = `sysctl -n hw.ncpu`.to_i
      @memory = `sysctl -n hw.memsize`.to_i / 1024
    end
  end

  class Windows < Generic
    def initialize
      @cpus = `wmic computersystem get numberofprocessors`.split("\n")[2].to_i
      @memory = `wmic OS get TotalVisibleMemorySize`.split("\n")[2].to_i / 1024
    end
  end
end
```

With that you can call `Platform.current` and you'll get an object with the information you need. Note I've moved `#reasonable_memory` to an instance method too (and used a neat little trick to find the median value).

One obvious improvement would of course be memoizing `Platform.current`, so it only bothers with instantiating something once.

As a sidenote: I don't actually use Rubocop, though I generally adhere to the style guide, and agree with very nearly all of it (I often link to it in reviews, too). I tested all the code above though, and Rubocop let me off with a warning about line length (and a broken tail light).

But running Rubocop on a little script like this is somewhat overkill. Like getting out [Strunk & White](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elements_of_Style) when writing a routine email. If you've used Rubocop for a while, I'm sure you've already learned to police your code yourself, and that's probably enough.